# How do I compile Xcode project through command line using Clang?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, info.plist

So, I am looking for a way to take fullscreen screenshots on OS X using C++. I found this sample code, which, I think, fits the purpose:

[ScreenSnapshot](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html)

It is an Xcode project. I managed to compile the .m and .h files using Clang by linking these:

```
-framework cocoa -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation -framework IOKit
```

Well, here is the problem. The executable spits out:

> No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the
>   Info.plist file, exiting

What is this Info.plist file? Can I avoid it?

Comment: This might help: [Capture Screen Image in C++ on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1537587/3425536)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked three separate questions in your question (avoid doing that, one question per question is the intended usage):

- How to compile Xcode project from command line?

  Just `cd` to the project root directory and run `xcodebuild`. The `.app` bundle will be placed under `build/Release` (might vary depending on your build location configurations in Xcode).
- How to take fullscreen screenshots on OS X using C++?

  There are plenty of duplicates here on Stack Overflow about this subject. Just search for "screenshot os x c++".
- What is `Info.plist` and can you avoid it?

  I cannot answer this so I'll leave it to someone else. There seems to be [pretty extensive documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) about it on the Apple Developer site (can be reached by googling "info.plist").

Comment: And the output is a folder full of crud :) I shall need to use this code with my other code, which is not xcode compatible. I need to use gcc (clang). If only your operation gave me an object file to which I could statically link...

Comment: …you're aware that "folder full of crud" is the standard way Mac OS X applications are bundled, right?

Comment: @duskwuff Yeah, I know. But can I statically link to anything inside the folder? I want the functionality to be built into my main program.

Comment: @user3496846 No. Read the sample code and reuse the appropriate parts. It's not complicated; the core of the application is literally a single function call.

Comment: @duskwuff actually thats right, the core is a couple of lines :) Thanks